# hasOwnProperty Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand the error message for `hasOwnProperty()` when it is invoked outside of the context of a defined object. i.e. instead of `myObj.hasOwnProperty('propName')` , just:

```
hasOwnProperty('propName')
```

The error message is:

> `VM269:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`
>      
> `at hasOwnProperty (<anonymous>)`
>      
> `at <anonymous>:1:1`

The error I was expecting:

> `VM280:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: hasOwnProperty is not defined`
>   
>     `at <anonymous>:1:1`

What exactly is it failing to convert?

```js
console.log(window.hasOwnProperty('blur'));
hasOwnProperty('propName');
```

---

#### Edit:

I think people are misinterpreting my question. I understand that you normally invoke this like `myObj.hasOwnProperty('propName')`. I want to better understand the error it is throwing. **What** exactly is it failing to convert? As @Felix stated, it should implicitly fall back to `window.hasOwnProperty('propName')`

---

#### Edit 2:

Interestingly, I took the Polyfill from [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) renamed it to `new_hasOwnProperty` and it works as expected:

```js
try{
    hasOwnProperty('blur');
}
catch(error) { console.log(error.message); }

// Polyfill
(function(w) {
  var isFunction = w.isFunction || (w.isFunction = function(x) {
      return typeof(x) === 'function'
    }),
    has = w.has || (w.has = function(o, p) {
      var e = p in o;
      return {
        value: e && (e = o[p]) && true,
        refer: e,
        valueOf: function() {
          return this.value
        }
      }
    }),
    Polyfill = w.PolyfillMethod || (w.PolyfillMethod = function(o, p, x) {
      var e = has(o, p);
      if (e && (e = isFunction(e.refer)) === false) {
        o[p] = x
      };
      return e
    }),
    theProto = w.Object.prototype;

  Polyfill(theProto, 'new_hasOwnProperty', function(x) {
    var o, e = this,
      p = String(x);
    return p in e && (o = e.__proto__ || e.constructor.prototype, (p in o === false) || e[p] !== o[p])
  });

})(window);

console.log(new_hasOwnProperty('blur'));
```

Comment: `hasOwnProperty` is a property of `window`, which makes it a global variable. But because it is called as a normal function (and probably through some other magic that makes `this` not refer to the global object), `this` is `undefined` and hence the function cannot work. Similar (though no error) for `toString()`.

Comment: Because no object is attached to it. Syntax should be Object.hasOwnProperty('propName'); https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Comment: @FelixKling Can you please elaborate - wouldn't the `this` context be preserved if it is implicitly referencing `window`?

Comment: its normal behaviour if you check on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Comment: In strict mode, `this` is `undefined` in a normal function call. Try `console.log(function() { "use strict"; return this; }())`. So no, it is not necessarily the global object. To be clear though: For any global function `foo`, `foo()` and `window.foo()` are two very different calls. The latter makes `this` be `window`. The former makes `this` either be `undefined` or `window`.

Comment: @FelixKling interesting... I made a second update to my question.

Comment: FWIW, this behavior is not likely not defined in the spec. As I said, properties of the global object become global variables. So `hasOwnProperty` exists, because it is a property of `window`. However, if you look at various browsers, `hasOwnProperty` is not an "own" property of `window`, it is specified somewhere in its prototype chain. *However*, the spec says about the global obejct *"has a [[Prototype]] internal slot whose value is implementation-dependent."* Additionally, `window` is a *host object*, meaning that can basically do whatever it wants.

Answer (score -1):

This error happens cause method expects `Object` to define if that `property` belongs to this `Object`.

You should use syntax like:

*`Object.hawOwnProperty(property)`*

Also you can to encounter such an error in places where the function expects an `Object` but gets `null`.

For example:

*`Object.keys(null)`*

Comment: This is incorrect. If it required `Object`, then it should have thrown `Uncaught ReferenceError: hasOwnProperty is not defined`. Because it didn't it means it implicitly falls back to `window.hasOwnProperty('property')`.

Comment: I'm think like we get another error, cause `hasOwnProperty` already defined, nope? Like if you will try to do `console.log(hasOwnProperty)` you will see like this is defined.

Comment: @Zze Also you can see like this is function by: `console.log(typeof hasOwnProperty);`

Comment: We can't to see code of that function, but we can research about it here:

https://cs.chromium.org/search/?q=function:hasOwnProperty+package:%5Echromium$+lang:%5Ejavascript$+function:hasOwnProperty&sq=package:chromium&type=cs